# Create and send envelope from composite template fails with ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I would like to create and send an envelope, composed from a template.
The template on the server pre-defines a **couple of **signer roles**, **subject** and **text** of the e-mail.

In the inline part I add:

- **2 signers**, one for each role, with name, email, signature provider info (basically only the phone number is missing in the role), SignHere Tab with with anchorString ending with '*'.
- **1 pdf document** with **4 signing fields**, 2 for each signer with a common prefix. Something like: "customer_1_sign_1", "customer_1_sign_2", "customer_2_sign_1", "customer_2_sign_2".

The intention is to assign signing field "customer_1*" to the first recipient (with has to be associated to the first **role**), and and "customer_2*" to the second recipient (assigned to the second role).

The create API fails with response:

```
{"errorCode":"ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED",
 "message":"Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts
            with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer."}
```

I cannot understand why it complains about "Freeform signing", while I set tabs for each sign filed group (based on a common prefix).

Here is the the log of an execution attempt:

```
TraceToken: 3c6f2283-f8bd-4c2e-8fd6-f596536cb3bc
Timestamp: 2021-11-19T14:00:17.8398210Z

POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2.1/accounts/72b8c45f-0720-4141-ab3d-efdb95122e64/envelopes
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 315096
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/3.15.0/java
X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 93.34.232.152

{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "1",
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "documents": [
            {
              "documentBase64": "<pdf document encoded in BASE64>",
              "documentId": "1",
              "fileExtension": "pdf",
              "name": "sample2",
              "transformPdfFields": "true"
            }
          ],
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "hilbert@xxxxx.it",
                "fullName": "Mick Hilbert",
                "name": "Mick Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00016005",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+39xxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE2",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "firmatario_00016005*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "hilbertsmike@xxxxx.it",
                "fullName": "Smike Hilbert",
                "name": "Smike Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00028471",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+39xxxxxxxxxx"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE1",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorString": "firmatario_00028471*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "2c9f039a-1306-4116-9083-096d9b68203b"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}

400 BadRequest

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 190
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 3c6f2283-f8bd-4c2e-8fd6-f596536cb3bc

{"errorCode":"ONESIGNALLSIGN_NOT_SATISFIED","message":"Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer."}
```

I also want to note that signing tabs are not intended to be inserted by DocuSign, but thea are olready present in the original document; I just want to assign the right tabs to each signer based on tab's identifier prefix.

I have tried to create the envelope without referring to the template, with exactly the same data, and it works perfectly, so it looks like the problem is strictly related to the template usage.

I tried both cases (with and without template) as draft, and than to complete the workflow (basically send the envelope) from the DocuSign web site. In the first case, the signing fields disappeared from the document, ant it force me to add some (for each signer) in order to let me send. In the second case, the signing fields are there, and I can just send it, without doing anything else.

I also tried to remove recipients from the template, and fill in all their information at runtime (instead of rely on roles), but the result does not change at all (tabs are removed from document), so there should be something wrong in the information I send to create envelope through composite template. But I copied them from the [DocuSign howto](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-composite-template-embedded/).

So now the question is: why creating the envelope by composite template results in signing fields (tabs) to be removed from documents?

Comment: can you try to create a new developer account, just for testing purpose, and try this code in there? I suspect your account have something enabled that conflicts with the ability to do free-form signing (such as part 11 for example)

Comment: This will allow you to create the envelope and then you can see which tabs were added for which recipient and see your issue without having an error.

Comment: One other thing to check - the anchor strings may not work because of the scope set for anchors. You may need to check it's for the entire envelope

Comment: Try to just add the tabs based on doc/page/x/y, again , just for testing, so you can isolate the issue.

Comment: free.form signing is intended to be inhibited. That's the reason why the document already  contains signing fields. We just want to assign the each field to the right recipient.

Comment: it is likely an issue with using anchor tags, or it can be that there's yet another recipient that you're not aware of. Try not to use "sent" but "created" like Drew suggested and see what you can find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in a comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184010/multiple-signers-pdf-transform-compositetemplate-and-wildcards). But I do not have any reference to official documentation stating it.

There was 2 issues preventing the request to be successfully processed:

- *tabLabel* property instead of *anchorString* has to be used (it accept wildcards too).
- document has to be assigned to property *document* of *CompositeTemplate*, instead of inside the *InlineTemplate*'s document list.

Note that, since *CompositeTemplate* can contain just one document, you need to define multiple *CompositeTemplates*, one for each document, each containing the *ServerTemplate* block and the recipient list in the *InlineTemplate*. Thus the recipients information are replicated.

Here is an example of request-log with 3 documents and 2 recipients:

```
TraceToken: d95c99fa-e05e-4c89-8801-00363b210a87
Timestamp: 2021-12-06T07:19:11.7302866Z

POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2.1/accounts/xxxxxx/envelopes
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 731974
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/3.15.0/java
X-DocuSign-SDK: Java
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 93.34.238.73

{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "0",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "<base64-encoded-pdf>",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "sample0",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "hilbertsmike@xxx.it",
                "name": "Smike Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00028471",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00028471\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "hilbert@xxx.it",
                "name": "Mick Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00016005",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00016005\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "7e82f2b4-0a1d-4145-b748-3a90eb001e5d"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "0",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "<base64-encoded-pdf>",
        "documentId": "2",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "sample2a",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "hilbertsmike@xxx.it",
                "name": "Smike Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00028471",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00028471\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "hilbert@xxx.it",
                "name": "Mick Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00016005",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00016005\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "7e82f2b4-0a1d-4145-b748-3a90eb001e5d"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "0",
      "document": {
        "documentBase64": "<base64-encoded-pdf>",
        "documentId": "3",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "sample2b",
        "transformPdfFields": "true"
      },
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "email": "hilbertsmike@xxx.it",
                "name": "Smike Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00028471",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00028471\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "email": "hilbert@xxx.it",
                "name": "Mick Hilbert",
                "recipientId": "00016005",
                "recipientSignatureProviders": [
                  {
                    "signatureProviderName": "intesa_tsp_aes",
                    "signatureProviderOptions": {
                      "sms": "+393201744869"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "roleName": "CLIENTE",
                "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                    {
                      "anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters": "true",
                      "tabLabel": "firmatario_00016005\\*"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": "2"
        }
      ],
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "sequence": "1",
          "templateId": "7e82f2b4-0a1d-4145-b748-3a90eb001e5d"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}

201 Created

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 173
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: d95c99fa-e05e-4c89-8801-00363b210a87

{"envelopeId":"2b54207d-c9cf-4b8b-ab11-5325c1b118aa","uri":"/envelopes/xxx","statusDateTime":"2021-12-06T07:19:11.1530000Z","status":"sent"}
```

Answer (score 2):

At face value, that error means that tags aren't being placed for at least one of your recipients. Since you're using anchor strings to place tags, you'll want to confirm your document is machine-readable. The most straightforward way to do this would be to start a draft in the web console using your document and try [to create auto-place tags](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience) using the same string you're using in your API Call.

Another test you could perform would be to change `"status":"sent"` to `"status":"created"` to generate a draft, then check that draft in the web console to see which recipient is missing tags.

Finally, I'm not sure it would cause the problem you're describing, but I notice you're defining RecipientIds along with the RoleName. In some cases, defining a recipient id can prevent the recipient role from matching correctly with the template - you might try this with the recipient ID removed to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: I tried to create the envelope in status "created". I found it in the "Draft" folder, but the unexpected event is that the signing fields in the document disappeared. But it looks correct, since have done the same operation without template, and the resulted documents looks the same, but the envelope is created and sent correctly.

Comment: I tried also without setting the recipientId, but I got this error: com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code 400 with response Body: '{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. 'recipientId' not set for recipient."}'

Comment: I have to retreat the first comment. If I try to complete the envelope-from-template from the docusign website, it force me to add at least one sign field (as confirm that the one predefined has been deleted during envelope creation). In the one created without template, in the "recipient preview" the signing field is already present, and I can directly send it, without inserting anything more.

Comment: Might be that the anchor strings are not being used for some reason. Can you try to change to fixed placement? if that's not it, it may be a recipient confusion with the template, meaning the one you see is not the one you put in the API call but coming from the template itself.